# How to compare sets of values pulled from a child/junction table?

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm relatively new to database work, so I may use some terms incorrectly. Please don't be misled by that.

Suppose I have three tables: Items, Customers, and a Junction table that connects the two. (This has nothing to do with my actual use case, so ignore anything that seems unreasonable. I'm just flavoring what is supposed to be an abstract example.)

Suppose the Items table has four records, the numbers 1 through 4. Suppose the Customers table has ten records, the letters A through J. Suppose this is the Junction table:

| Item | Customer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | H |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | H |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | C |
| 3 | H |
| 4 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 4 | E |

The sort on this table makes it easy to see that there is a sense in which it maps Items to sets of Customers, like so:

| Item | Customer_Set |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {A, C, H} |
| 2 | {A, H} |
| 3 | {A, C, H} |
| 4 | {C, D, E} |

I'm looking for ways to compare these set mappings. Let X and Y be any two Items, and let J(X) be the set of Customers to which X is mapped by the junction table. I want to be able to answer the following questions:

1. Is J(X) = J(Y)? [Extensionally, so not taking order into account]
2. Is J(X) a subset of J(Y)?
3. Does J(X) partially overlap J(Y)? If so, what is their intersection?

It seems like these should all be pretty basic questions from a computation standpoint. I refuse to believe that there's not a way to do this. If it is impossible in Access, but possible in some other system, could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your table is `t`. Bearing in mind that we can think about the following definitions:

- item_1 is an item being compared
- customer_1 is the customer of an item being compared
- item_2 is the item being compared with item_1
- customer_2 is the customer of the item being compared with item_1

Then you might do this:

```
SELECT x.item AS item_1, x.customer AS customer_1, y.item AS item_2, y.customer AS customer_2
FROM t AS x
     INNER JOIN t AS y ON x.item <> y.item AND x.customer = Y.customer
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT x.item, x.customer, y.item, null
FROM t AS x
     LEFT JOIN t AS y ON x.item <> y.item
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t AS z WHERE z.item = y.item AND z.customer = x.customer)
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT y.item, NULL, x.item, x.customer
FROM t AS x
     RIGHT JOIN t AS y ON x.item <> y.item
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t AS z WHERE z.item = y.item AND z.customer = x.customer)
ORDER BY item_1, item_2, customer_1;
```

This query has three parts.

**Part 1 - get the rows where the item is different and the customer is the same**

```
SELECT x.item AS item_1, x.customer AS customer_1, y.item AS item_2, y.customer AS customer_2
FROM t AS x
     INNER JOIN t AS y ON x.item <> y.item AND x.customer = Y.customer
```

**Part 2 - get the rows where the item is different and the customer for item_1 does not exist in the list of customers for item_2**

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.item, x.customer, y.item, null
FROM t AS x
     LEFT JOIN t AS y ON x.item <> y.item
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t AS z WHERE z.item = y.item AND z.customer = x.customer)
```

**Part 3 - get the rows where the item is different and the customer of item_2 does not exist in the list of customers from item_1**

```
SELECT DISTINCT y.item, NULL, x.item, x.customer
FROM t AS x
     RIGHT JOIN t AS y ON x.item <> y.item
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t AS z WHERE z.item = y.item AND z.customer = x.customer)
```

Considering the case where item_1 = 1. The goal is to compare each of the customer sets of items 2 - 4 with the customer set of item 1. The result is as follows (I've pasted it in Excel so I can annotate it)

[image]

Now suppose you use that query and save it as a view in your database called [comparisons], then you can do something like this (among other things):

```
SELECT item_1,
       item_2,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT customer_1) = COUNT(DISTINCT customer_2) 
            THEN 'set is the same size' ELSE 'set is not the same size' 
            END AS set_size_comparison,
       CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN customer_1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> 0 
            THEN 'item_2 has customers not present in item_1' ELSE 'item_1 entirely contains item_2' 
            END AS check_1,
       CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN customer_2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> 0 
            THEN 'item_1 has customers not present in item_2' ELSE 'item_2 entirely contains item_1' 
            END AS check_2
FROM comparisons
WHERE item_1 = 1
GROUP BY item_1, item_2;
```

| item_1 | item_2 | set_size_comparison | check_1 | check_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | set is not the same size | item_1 entirely contains item_2 | item_1 has customers not present in item_2 |
| 1 | 3 | set is the same size | item_1 entirely contains item_2 | item_2 entirely contains item_1 |
| 1 | 4 | set is the same size | item_2 has customers not present in item_1 | item_1 has customers not present in item_2 |

Comment: YOU. ARE. A. GOD.